# I want my homepage navbar to have different styling to the rest of my site, how can I do this?

Tags: menus, genesis-theme-framework

I am using the genesis framework, all I literally want to do is remove the navbar background colour for the homepage only. All my attempted changes have affected all the navigation menus.

Comment: Sorry but your question is not WordPress specific, it is 100% `CSS` related. Be aware that a) this question could be put on hold because it is off topic and b) problems with 3rd party `themes` or `plugins` should be solved at the forums as offered by their `theme` developers.For `CSS` questions/answers look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the question is css related. Anyway if you need modify the output html of your navs using Walker Class

For more information check... [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker)

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with the Genesis Framework, but most WordPress themes automatically add the "home" class to the `<body>` tag. So to change the navbar on the home page only you would have to use a CSS selector like this:

```
.home .yourNavBarClass {
    background: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple 'hack' to add custom class to navbar only for home page is to check if current page is home page and then assign a class to it like this: `class="<?php if(is_home() || is_front_page()) { echo "class_name"; }?>"`

Then you can do whatever you want with css, for example:

```
.class_name {
  background-color: white;
}
```